# Shimano caliper not sitting properly on fork (gets angled)

Tags: mountain-bike, disc-brake, fork

I just bought a new mountain bike equiped with **Shimano M365s** and **RST Blaze** fork and I've been through the bedding process.

I noticed that my front brake is rubbing a lot, and when i tried to fix it, I realised that **the caliper is not seated straight on the fork**. Also, the disk is a bit bent but i suspect that's coming for the hub itself as the bike is brand new.

When i try to center the caliper it sits perfectly on the disk, but **when i tighten it, it gets a bad angle** and rubs unevenly on the disk.

I suspect it's something to do with the washers as they not sit straight when the bolt is tightened.

[image][image]

Comment: Normal procedure that you probably followed: Un-tighten the two bolts, pull the the brake lever while softly tapping the calliper. KEEP the lever pulled and re-tighten the bolts in two steps at least. Then only release the lever.

Comment: Yeap that's correct

Comment: Do the calipers come with conical washers?

Comment: yes. If you look really closely at the bottom one, you can see it's not really straight.

Comment: Concave/Convex washers need a pair on each bolt - i.e. a Caliper needs 8 washers.  Your mount is missing  the bottom ones. I don't recall any Shimano braking using these - they are mostly used on Avids.   My first reaction is check the brakes are correctly assembled accornding to Shimano installation instructions. I have seen this done by a bike shop when the bolts were too long - I presume fitting washers was easier, quicker or cheaper than finding the correct mounting bolts.

Comment: I checked the official documents and it's installed correctly. As a temp solution, i used 2 small pieces of an old tube to force the caliper sit at 0deg. I know it's not safe but at least i can ride to the bike shop!

Comment: @mattnz Most current Shimano brakes have one set of them installed just like in the picture. They're to keep slight misalignment between the bolt threads and post mount face from affecting the alignment of the caliper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First double check the wheel is fully seated in the frame. If it is, and the caliper is sitting at an angle no matter what you do, it's a sign the post mounts need  to be faced, which essentially is a shop job unless you buy a fairly expensive tool. This isn't common on new suspension forks for whatever reason, although you see it out of the box on frames quite a bit presently. Hopefully whoever you bought it from just takes care of it for you.

A related problem arises if the mounting bolts have been overtightened and caused the post mount or adapter to dent a depression into the surface of the caliper. That doesn't really happen on relatively chunky mounts like these though, more the dainty rounded ones that some bikes use.

Comment: That is some great information. I had no idea that "facing" was a thing. I will go the shop but most likely they will call me "crazy" (pretty common in my 3rd world country). Thanks a lot, i will let you know!

Comment: I took it to the LBS and the mechanic trimmed the fork mount and added a washer to compensate. Took 5 mins. Thanks :)